# Will too many tags cause any issues in Git?

Tags: git

I have to create several tags every day in a Git repository.
When I have lots of tags, will it make my repository sluggish or cause other issues?

Note: I'm using GitHub, but please answer generically.

Comment: AFAIK a tag is just a pointer to a commit. If a service like github has to do extra processing for each tag, it might be slower to update on the website, but git itself shouldn't slow down, except maybe `git log` if you have a few million tags.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[(Annotated) tags](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References#Tags) won't make Git sluggish, only harder to use in that you will have an harder time to find relevant tags amongst all the intermediate ones.

Worst case, it can make your web interface (like GitHub) sluggish if it has to display *thousands* of tags.

Maybe all those tags don't need to be pushed, in which case you could consider making intermediate local ["Lightweight" tags](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging#Lightweight-Tags).

Comment: @VonC I need to push them, they'll be used later by other users. I was wondering whether I would need to clean the older ones.

Comment: @ML-- you can clean them, first locally then on the remote: `git tag -d 12.15`, `git push origin :refs/tags/12.15`. However, your colleagues might have an harder time to synchronize: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1841341/remove-local-tags-that-are-no-longer-on-the-remote-repository

Comment: @VonC thanks. That question's OP and I are doing the same thing. Since all those tags will hardly cause a negative impact, I'm fine. I'll leave them there.

Comment: `only annotated tags can be pushed` this is not accurate.  I just created and pushed a lightweight tag.

Comment: @MattFenwick Yes (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822098/can-i-have-private-git-tags-that-are-not-sent-via-a-push), I meant "only annotated tag *should* be pushed (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064499/unable-to-see-a-list-of-git-tags/1064505#1064505 and http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0506.2/2023.html, after http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1793781/git-global-tags-evidently-bad-but-why). I have deleted my previous comment to avoid confusion.

Comment: @J-16SDiZ Actually, lightweight tags can be pushed, but shouldn't. See the references I mention in my previous comment to MattFenwick.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, *many* tags can slow down some of your everyday git commands, including `git pull`, `git fetch` and `git push`. But you shouldn't worry about it unless you have many thousands of them.

I work on a monorepo that currently has 102,448 tags (`git tag | wc -l`). Our Jenkins pipeline tags every single build it creates, whether it is a pull request build or a release build. Here's how that affects `git fetch`:

```bash
$ time git fetch

________________________________________________________
Executed in   65.70 secs    fish           external
   usr time    2.60 secs    0.11 millis    2.60 secs
   sys time    0.84 secs    1.30 millis    0.84 secs
```

Here's how quick it goes with `--no-tags`:

```bash
$ time git fetch --no-tags

________________________________________________________
Executed in    3.17 secs      fish           external
   usr time  943.50 millis    0.09 millis  943.41 millis
   sys time   60.52 millis    1.02 millis   59.49 millis
```

That's over a minute difference. You can make `--no-tags` the default (if you have a lot of tags) by setting this on your config:

```bash
$ git config --add remote.origin.tagopt --no-tags
```

Swap `origin` for a different remote if you need to. It's a similar story for `git push`, even if there are no changes between the local and remote.

```bash
$ time git push
Everything up-to-date

________________________________________________________
Executed in   50.60 secs      fish           external
   usr time  701.75 millis    0.07 millis  701.68 millis
   sys time  401.84 millis    1.12 millis  400.71 millis
```

So what's going on? You can inspect the traffic by using the `GIT_TRACE_PACKET` environment variable:

```bash
$ env GIT_TRACE_PACKET=2 git push
```

Somewhere in the output you'll see many lines like this, one for each tag you have:

```
08:38:56.890217 pkt-line.c:80           packet:         push< dca8b5a27bab04c286d4b55e47df22303e06295d refs/tags/actions/2.0.569-PR-31183-1839146375
```

The only downside is, with `git push` there is no config to avoid the packets for each tag.

Answer (score 6):

Using Git 2.8.1 on Windows, I have experienced minor slowness from certain commands when there are lots of tags (15000 or so), including:

- `git log` (with `--decorate`)
- `git status`
- Viewing history in Visual Studio.
- Using the command prompt when head is detached (since Git Bash pretty-prints the current revision next to the current directory).

These commands all examine tags to decorate revisions shown.  Each of these commands takes about 1-2 seconds longer than without the tags.

**Update:** Running `git gc` (without `--prune` as I had been) greatly sped up Git.  The real culprit may have been frequent rebasing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using 3-digit version numbers for tags on what I release to coworkers. This leads to logistic issues because I'd like to release with an even finer granularity.

I was always worried that more frequent tags would slow the Git repository down, but the answers given here, definitely take that concern away.

I will now move to the 4-digit style as shown in an example of the link given by @VonC : ["Lightweight" tags](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tagging#Lightweight-Tags). I should have done that earlier. And I'll be going for the full-blown "Annotated" tags. With less than 10 releases per month, Git won't even notice.