# git push tags stuck most of the time

Tags: git, git-tag

I have build machine that runs every night, it builds my project (iOS) and pushes to git repository with new tag.

So far I have 400 tags in remote repo.

I run following:

```
$ git commit -am "Jenkins auto build"

$ git tag $JENKINS_BUILD_VERSION

$ git push --tags -u origin master
```

The last command stuck in 80% of run, I think it might be because remote repo has 400 tags or I miss something?

Can somebody help me to fix this issue?

Maybe I need to change `$ git push --tags -u origin master` to something else?

Thanks,

Comment: The number of tags is not supposed to have any impact, at least according to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10612742/will-too-many-tags-cause-any-issues-in-git) So, perhaps it is a matter of connection from your jenkins to your git repo?